# Mysql - Fields in views and tables being cut off at a character limit for varchar?

Tags: mysql, view, windows

I have tables where I am running views off of.   Anything with  over varchar(255) get automatically cut off in a view.

I even created a query to create a table using AS SELECT (that was a view) with the right thresholds set for each field... and it still gets cut off at the same spot.

What setting is this and why when I create a table with varchar(1000) - and this is verified - does it only show 255 characters???

---

Steps for view.   I created a test table to reproduce it.

1. Table testlimit

- test1 varchar (255)
- test2 varchar (1000)

2. Populated a couple rows.   One of the rows have longer than 255 characters for test2 field.
3. Creating view...
   select * from testlimit.
4. Boom the longer data is trimmed for field test2.

Also Example #2....

Building a query to reproduce it as a table.

1. CREATE TABLE testlimit2 AS
   SELECT * FROM testlimit.
2. Open up new testlimit2 table and shows test2 as varchar(1000).
3. Data for test2 is still trimmed.

Also Example #3...

CREATE TABLE testlimit_commaexplode
SELECT
test1
TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`test2`, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1)) test_sep,
FROM
testlimit
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10) n
ON LENGTH(REPLACE(`test2`, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(`test2`)-n.digit

- This example pulls comma separated field so that each item has its own row.    This fails too and the data is trimmed at the exact same spot as the view and create table - in some examples it trims off 3+ rows.

I use navicat to build thing but not sure how the software would effect that.   CharacterSet - utf8, collation utf8_general_ci.

**New Update**

The server seemed to be acting wonky all the way around.   Many weird issues so I decided to reboot.    After rebooting I did some tests after and wow was I surprised...

In our main tables - that haven't changed in years - and that have varchar(1000) set for some larger rows...   they are still cut off.    Not surprised there.    I tried to load the import file again...   Again tells me there are no changes to be made (even though for several rows the import file has the extra characters for thousands of rows).

So I decide to create new tables and import the data.   I make it really easy and import just our primary key and one of the long columns.    I choose varchar(1000)...   Fails to import.   Even though I just imported this same file above (with more rows/fields).    The data being imported for sure does not have 1000 characters.

I then create a new table and import the same small test file, this time choose text as my column type.   Boom everything works - no trimming off the data.   I verified in creating a new view and all of the data is still there.

So I will update the question to be more accurate.    How/What broke my varchar fields??    These things have worked for YEARS.   Was there some sort of update that snuck in that changed this in the past few weeks??   Navicat I haven't changed in years and server doesn't even have access for this.    Windows is company controlled so yes it could at anytime.    I don't believe MySQL could update but I guess it is possible.

> Here is an example of the truncation - and note that I tried many
> times to just type in random letters (to rule out "/" and "&")and got the same limit:
>
> **In Database after "Bug"**
> Commercial & Retail Bank, Investment Bank /
> M&A Advisory, Broker-Dealer, Inter-Dealer Broker, Exchange,
> Independent Research, Clearing & Securities Services, Asset Management
> & Investment Advisory, Hedge Fund, Insurance, Private Equity / Venture
> Capital,
>
> **In Database Before "Bug"**
> Commercial & Retail Bank, Investment Bank /
> M&A Advisory, Broker-Dealer, Inter-Dealer Broker, Exchange,
> Independent Research, Clearing & Securities Services, Asset Management
> & Investment Advisory, Hedge Fund, Insurance, Private Equity / Venture
> Capital, Custody & Fund Accounting, Corporate Energy & Basic
> Materials, Corporate Consulting & Advisory, Corporate Retail,
> Corporate Technology, Corporate Other, Government, Academia, Media,
> Individual Investor

The example above is kind of crazy because every way I massage the table, it creates the bug.   So before "bug" is just the same table from last week.   If I import data to this, if I create a view, even if I try to switch the longer columns to text.... boom bug hits and data is chopped off.    I have data backups and I think I can start fresh and create the tables using text fields but this is crazy that it has worked as is for year and BOOM stopped working.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142777/discussion-on-question-by-lostindb-mysql-fields-in-views-and-tables-being-cut); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a known bug in excel.    The input file I was getting in excel started having non-utf8 characters.     Mainly the single quote.     This for a lack of a better term wigged out my table and what happened is after it uploaded into mysql it locked all of those fields to 255 characters which is another known bug in mysql that derives from the excel issue.

Even when adjust the fields to TEXT the schema was locked.   Using a goofy work around I was able to change the field to MEMO and it alleviated issue.    I decided better was to just revert entire database tables back before bug and resave input files as csv.   I could see that the csv files had non-utf8 characters - which did not show in excel...

Anyways the tables are updated with the exact same input file saved as csv and the tables reverting back a few weeks don't have the schema lock issues.    There were some very very goofy work arounds for the excel issue - one that I verified that work is make the column name greater than 255 - but I just thought it simpler to change to csv.

So the two points here:

1. Your tables can get "altered/corrupt" during an input that isn't compatible.
2. Excel format has some innate issues for inputting.

Comment: @RickJames - thanks for helping on this.   Feel free to post a better answer than mine.   I left this in case others have the same issue and there answers on SO for the excel 255 issue...  I am not sure why my tables got "messed up" because of an input file though.